# How to check if pppoe is already connected in windows through a cmd?

Tags: windows, terminal, internet, cmd.exe

I have accomplished auto wifi connecting and then connecting pppoe as I have scheduled the script to run every 5 minutes so it disconnects my wifi when it runs if it's already connected..!
I want to be able like when the script runs it will check first that if the pc is connected to specific wlan profile name and then check if pppoe is connected right after that if pppoe is connected if pppoe is connected so it will ping a site to confirm that internet is available and if internet is available so it will leave it otherwise if if wifi is not connected so it repeat the same process like as in script :

```
netsh wlan connect name=Fursan-WIFI-03049815768
rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE admin thedarkforce 
rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE /d
rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE admin thedarkforce
```

I figure I could do this as an if loop, but I'm unsure how to script a loop in windows. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PING test before it. How reliable it will be I don't know, but certainly more reliable than just calling it regardless:

```
set ipToTest=8.8.8.8
ping -n 1 %ipToTest% | find "TTL"
if %errorlevel% == 1 (
    netsh wlan connect name=Fursan-WIFI-03049815768
    if %errorlevel% == 1 (
        netsh wlan connect name=DIFFERENT_NETWORK_HERE
    )
    rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE admin thedarkforce 
    rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE /d
    rasdial MikroTik_PPPoE admin thedarkforce 
)
```

Using Google's DNS as a test, but you can change that to any IP you want. This will only run your commands if the PING fails for some reason.

Personally, I don't think this is a great solution, your connection shouldn't be dropping regularly enough to warrant this. Sounds like something, somewhere, might need replacement or fixing, and this is only a band aid measure that, although not every 5 minutes with this change, may cause you issues if you're streaming or in the middle of a download.

Comment: Well...I have electricity on off issue here so that's  why...it drops and as from now onwards in Windows 8 and 10 PPPoE do not auto connects so that's why..!

Comment: Also how can I make sure if that specific wifi is not available so then connect to another specific wifi like to give it multiple options..??

Comment: @UmarShah You can do it the same way - updated my answer.